# XSL transform MS Access 2007 output

Tags: xml, ms-access, xslt, transformation, export-to-xml

I am exporting data from Access on regular basis. So far I used to export it and manually edit some tags to adjust it to Clients needs. Lately I found that that there is posibility to use XSL as a transformation pattern.

I am still beginner when comes to XSL but managed to create something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dataroot/Kwerenda_x0020_Nota_x0020_Kredytowa">
    <xsl:element name="Faktury_od_nas">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Generally it works ok but:
1. Normally when I export data it gives me every tag in a new line, now it is divided only by tag I changed.
2. I do not know how to rename dataroot. I tried to copy/paste same code but then I get dataroot everytime Faktury_od_nas appears...

Transformed sample data:

```
<dataroot generated="2016-01-12T13:54:11" xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata"><Faktury_od_nas><No>1</No><InvoiceDate>20150715</InvoiceDate><InvoiceNumber>12345</InvoiceNumber><CustVATNumber>LT100004645417</CustVATNumber><E100customerKey>65-92</E100customerKey><CustomerName>Client_name</CustomerName><InvoiceCountry>BE</InvoiceCountry><VATpersent>21</VATpersent><VATBasis>106,36</VATBasis><VATamount>22,34</VATamount><Currency>EUR</Currency><VAT_x0020_recovery_x0020_fee_x0020_rate_x0020__x0028__x0025__x0029_>7.5</VAT_x0020_recovery_x0020_fee_x0020_rate_x0020__x0028__x0025__x0029_><Service_x0020_Type>Express</Service_x0020_Type><InvoiceScanFileName>scan_name</InvoiceScanFileName>
    </Faktury_od_nas></dararoot>
```

Desired sample data:

```
<Faktura>
<Faktury_od_nas>
<No>1</No>
<InvoiceDate>20150715</InvoiceDate>
<InvoiceNumber>12345</InvoiceNumber>
<CustVATNumber>LT100004645417</CustVATNumber>
<E100customerKey>65-92</E100customerKey>
<CustomerName>Client_name</CustomerName>
<InvoiceCountry>BE</InvoiceCountry>
<VATpersent>21</VATpersent>
<VATBasis>106,36</VATBasis>
<VATamount>22,34</VATamount>
<Currency>EUR</Currency>
<VAT_x0020_recovery_x0020_fee_x0020_rate_x0020__x0028__x0025__x0029_>7.5</VAT_x0020_recovery_x0020_fee_x0020_rate_x0020__x0028__x0025__x0029_>
<Service_x0020_Type>Express</Service_x0020_Type>
<InvoiceScanFileName>scan_name</InvoiceScanFileName>
</Faktury_od_nas>
</Faktura>
```

I appreciate any help.

Edit:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dataroot">
    <Faktura>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </Faktura>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Kwerenda_x0020_Nota_x0020_Kredytowa">
    <Faktury_od_nas>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </Faktury_od_nas>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your desired output is not well-formed XML!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help seeing your source XML, but I believe you could use:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dataroot">
    <Faktura>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </Faktura>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Kwerenda_x0020_Nota_x0020_Kredytowa">
    <Faktury_od_nas>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </Faktury_od_nas>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Almost there. As you can see in a `transformed sample data`, `dataroot` has some additional information: `generated=""` and `xmlns:od=""`. When I applied your code I get in every child of `Faktury_od_nas` information `xmlns:od=""`. It should just erased from `dataroot`.

Comment: Only one small detail remained. First line now looks like: `<?xml version="1.0"?>`, it misses encoding information: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`. Any chance fixing this?

Comment: Are you sure you have the `encoding` attribute on the `xsl:output` element?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. The XSLT 1.0 standard requires the XML declaration to include both version information and an encoding declaration. Perhaps you need to set up your XSLT processor to conform - I am afraid I wouldn't know anything about that.

Comment: Well XSLT processor is MS Access. I click export to XML -> filename -> transform -> select file and done. When I was using my code I received `encoding="UTF-16"` (no idea why UTF-16...). When started using your code encoding part was lost.

Comment: I suggest you post a separate question, tagged with MS Access. This is not about XSLT as such and, as I said, I don't know anything about Access.

Comment: It is marked as MS Access from the beginning (title and tag). Anyway thank you for efforts. Maybe I will find out what is wrong later and write here. You were a great help (now only encoding part is missing!).

Comment: Ah, right. I would still post this as a separate question.

Comment: Use @michael.hor257k's answer, but separate the processing with VBA code (not via ribbon icon): 1) Export XML with [Application.ExportXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193212.aspx) and 2) Transform XML with [Application.TransformXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844810.aspx) which can be limited, so consider using the [VBA MSMXL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33921974/ms-access-to-xml-saved-export-produces-different-xml-structure-when-re-exporte/33947818#33947818) approach (loading your XSLT externally or embedded as a VBA string).

Comment: @Parfait, I do not actually want to use VBA. So far I did all the job but someone is going to replace me (for now this going to be a person having no programming knowledge and so I need to make it in a different way than usual).

Comment: I have found similar topic or at least talking about my problem, I guess it is not possible to receive UTF-8 that easily. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5302858/xslcompiledtransform-uses-utf-16-encoding

Comment: It seems like has to be changed manually or using VBA procedure recommended by Parfait.

Comment: Anyway, for now I am going to accept your anwser :)