# Specify exact XML export structure in MS Access 2013

Tags: xml, database, ms-access, xslt, export

I have an MS Access database containing course data which is regularly exported to XML to provide data for a website.

The tables I need to export are a primary `Courses` table, plus several other directly related and indirectly related tables such as `Occurrences`, `OccurrencesUnits`, `Units`, `Locations`, `Staff`, `SubjectAreas`, etc.

With the help of my previous [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33921974/ms-access-to-xml-saved-export-produces-different-xml-structure-when-re-exporte) (may be worth reading for some background info) I was able to set up the exact XML structure needed, which is simplified below:

```
    <Courses>
            <CourseID>1</CourseID>
            <CourseTitle>Meat Science</CourseTitle>
            (etc etc)
            <Occurrences>
                    <OccurrenceID>1</OccurrenceID>
                    <OccurrenceTitle>Meat Science Autumn 2016</OccurrenceTitle>
                    <CourseID>1</CourseID>
                    <OccurrencesUnits>
                            <OccurrencesUnitsID>1</OccurrencesUnitsID>
                            <OccurrenceID>1</OccurrenceID>
                            <UnitID>1</UnitID>
                    </OccurrencesUnits>
            </Occurrences>
    </Courses>

    <Courses>
       ... more courses...
    </Courses>

    <Units>
       ...
    </Units>

    <Locations>
       ...
    </Locations>

    <Staff>
       ...
    </Staff>

    <SubjectAreas>
       ...
    </SubjectAreas>

    etc etc
```

So there are a few tiers whereby the `Occurrences` and then `OccurrencesUnits` tables are nested inside each of their `Courses` entries, but then all the other related tables need to be listed underneath (not nested).

However, on recently upgrading from Access 2010 to 2013 I have found that I cannot produce the same structure. It seems that Access 2013 takes into account table relationships by nesting any *directly related* tables into the primary table nodes by default. When specifying the layout structure via XSL (as per my related Stack Overflow question, linked above), this leads to the *directly* related tables being omitted from the XML export, unlike in 2010 where they automatically appeared underneath the `Courses`.

I found that another person on accessforums.net has identified a similar problem: http://www.accessforums.net/showthread.php?t=46933 Their solution was to delete the table relationships in Access, which in fairness does lead to the intended XML output but would presumably be rather bad for my database!

For info, my VBA export code in Access looks like this:

```
Private Sub ExportCourseCatalogXML_Click()

  Dim rawDoc As Object, xslDoc As Object, newDoc As Object
  Dim xmlstr As String, xslstr As String
  Dim otherTables As AdditionalData

  Set otherTables = Application.CreateAdditionalData
  otherTables.Add "Occurrences"
  otherTables.Add "OccurrencesUnits"
  otherTables.Add "Units"
  otherTables.Add "Locations"
  otherTables.Add "CourseSubcategories"
  otherTables.Add "CourseTags"
  otherTables.Add "Partners"
  otherTables.Add "Staff"
  otherTables.Add "SubjectAreas"

  Application.ExportXML acExportTable, "Courses", "S:\Science\Biosciences\AATP\Database\xml\course-catalog.xml", _
             , , , , , , AdditionalData:=otherTables

  ' LOAD XML AND XSL FILES '
  xmlstr = "C:\path\to\course-catalog.xml"
  xslstr = "C:\path\to\structure.xsl"

  Set rawDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
  Set xslDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
  Set newDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

  rawDoc.async = False
  rawDoc.Load xmlstr

  xslDoc.async = False
  xslDoc.Load xslstr

  ' TRANSFORM TO NEW XML '
  rawDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc

  ' SAVE NEW XML FILE '
  newDoc.Save "C:\path\to\course-catalog.xml"

  MsgBox "Successfully exported XML.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

and my `structure.xsl` looks like this:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
           xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"               
           exclude-result-prefixes="od xsi">

<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- Identity Transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Courses">
  <Courses>
      <xsl:copy-of select="CourseID"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="CourseTitle"/>
      (etc etc)
      <xsl:for-each select="Occurrences">
      <Occurrences>
         <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
         <xsl:variable name="occid" select="occurrenceID"/>
         <xsl:copy-of select="../../OccurrencesUnits[CourseOccurrence=$occid]"/>
      </Occurrences>
      </xsl:for-each>        
  </Courses>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="OccurrencesUnits"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

So my question - Is it possible to specify (presumably via XSL) the exact structure I require, i.e. all tables listed *outside* of `Courses` except for `Occurrences` and `OccurrencesUnits`? Many thanks in advance for any support on this!

**Added 17th Aug 2016:**

For clarification, the XML that MS Access 2013 produces can be seen below. It is similar to 2010, but the problem is that any tables that are *directly* related to the Courses table are omitted (`CourseSubcategories`, `CourseTags`, `Partners`, `Staff` and `SubjectAreas`), and the only way to include them is to delete their relationships to `Courses` in Access. The tables of `Units` and `Locations` *are* included (because they are *not directly related* to `Courses`).

```
<Courses>
        <CourseID>1</CourseID>
        <CourseTitle>Meat Science</CourseTitle>
        (etc etc)
        <Occurrences>
                <OccurrenceID>1</OccurrenceID>
                <OccurrenceTitle>Meat Science Autumn 2016</OccurrenceTitle>
                <CourseID>1</CourseID>
                <OccurrencesUnits>
                        <OccurrencesUnitsID>1</OccurrencesUnitsID>
                        <OccurrenceID>1</OccurrenceID>
                        <UnitID>1</UnitID>
                </OccurrencesUnits>
        </Occurrences>
</Courses>

<Courses>
   ... more courses...
</Courses>

<Units>
   ...
</Units>

<Locations>
   ...
</Locations>
```

Comment: Can you show current XML output? And does it do like your posted link of similar question where only the last record in other tables are nested?

Comment: Have now posted current XML output above - Hope that helps. And sorry, not sure what you mean in your 2nd question - I haven't noticed any issues with individual records from a table behaving differently from the rest of the records in that table.

Comment: Do those table nodes show up on the raw XML (before transformation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider exporting individual temp xml files for those related tables that do not appear. Then, include those xmls in the XSLT transformation using the [`document()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256465(v=vs.110).aspx) function. VBA will delete them after transformation. One very important setup in this approach is the XSLT (.xsl) script must reside in same folder as the XML files as it makes relative file references:

**VBA**

```vb
Private Sub ExportCourseCatalogXML_Click()

  Dim rawDoc As Object, xslDoc As Object, newDoc As Object
  Dim xmlstr As String, xslstr As String
  Dim otherTables As AdditionalData
  Dim temp As Variant

  Set otherTables = Application.CreateAdditionalData
  otherTables.Add "Occurrences"
  otherTables.Add "OccurrencesUnits"

  ' EXPORT MAIN XML 
  Application.ExportXML acExportTable, "Courses", "S:\Science\Biosciences\AATP\Database\xml\course-catalog.xml", _
             , , , , , , AdditionalData:=otherTables

  ' EXPORT TEMP XMLS
  For Each temp in Array("Units", "Locations", "CourseSubcategories", "CourseTags", "Partners", "Staff", "SubjectAreas")
      Application.ExportXML acExportTable, temp, "S:\Science\Biosciences\AATP\Database\xml\" & temp & ".xml" 
  Next temp 

  ' LOAD XML AND XSL FILES '
  xmlstr = "C:\path\to\course-catalog.xml"
  xslstr = "C:\path\to\structure.xsl"

  Set rawDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
  Set xslDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
  Set newDoc = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")

  rawDoc.async = False
  rawDoc.setProperty "AllowDocumentFunction", True
  rawDoc.Load xmlstr

  xslDoc.async = False
  xslDoc.setProperty "AllowDocumentFunction", True
  xslDoc.Load xslstr

  ' TRANSFORM TO NEW XML '
  rawDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc

  ' SAVE NEW XML FILE '
  newDoc.Save "C:\path\to\course-catalog.xml"

  ' DELETE TEMP XMLs
  For Each temp in Array("Units", "Locations", "CourseSubcategories", "CourseTags", "Partners", "Staff", "SubjectAreas")
      xmlfile = "S:\Science\Biosciences\AATP\Database\xml\" & temp & ".xml"
      If Len(Dir(xmlfile, vbDirectory)) > 0 Then Kill xmlfile
  Next temp 

  MsgBox "Successfully exported XML.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

**XSLT** *(must be saved in same directory as other .xml files)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
           xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"               
           exclude-result-prefixes="od xsi">

<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/dataroot">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="document('CourseSubcategories.xml')/dataroot/CourseSubcategories"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="document('CourseTags.xml')/dataroot/CourseTags"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="document('Partners.xml')/dataroot/Partners"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="document('Staff.xml')/dataroot/Staff"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="document('SubjectAreas.xml')/dataroot/SubjectAreas"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Courses">
  <Courses>
      <xsl:copy-of select="CourseID"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="CourseTitle"/>
      (etc etc)
      <xsl:for-each select="Occurrences">
      <Occurrences>
         <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
         <xsl:variable name="occid" select="occurrenceID"/>
         <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::dataroot/OccurrencesUnits[CourseOccurrence=$occid]"/>
      </Occurrences>
      </xsl:for-each>        
  </Courses>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="OccurrencesUnits"/>

</xsl:transform>
```

Comment: Brilliant, this works! Had to tweak a few things: I removed several of the tables from the 'otherTables' object and also added `Units` and `Locations` to the arrays to handle them in the same way as the directly related tables otherwise the output was not properly formed. I also found that `setProperty` was causing VBA errors so I changed it to `rawDoc.SetProperty "AllowDocumentFunction", True`. Finally, in the XSLT the `ancestor::Courses/` selection was not working so reverted back to `../../`. Now works perfectly - Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Indeed, as I do not have your database tables, code adjustments would be needed and I almost added a note to that effect. Other OPs on StackOverflow expect exact perfect code or your answer is wrong! Also, I believe it should be `ancestor::dataroot/` the preferred, more defined XPath expression.